# Showing Suggestion box for multiple email ids with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

I have created an angular JS function to show email suggestions from Google Admin Directory.I am calling a Service inside the Angular JS function to get the emails. Now i want to mark the form submission to  multiple employees by adding their emails in the above text field, but the suggestions with list of emails only show for one employee,Is there a simple way to show suggestions when am adding multiple emails in the text field

Below is the angular JS function

```
  $scope.getEmail= function(val) {
            return $http.get('https://1-dot-   directory.appspot.com/_ah/api/mydirectory/v1/query/'+val)
            .then(function(response){
              return response.data.items.map(function(item){

               return item.email;

               });
            });
          };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first show the names of the persons ? and if you have selected a person you can show all the emails ? if they have more then one.

Comment: No , The email id's should come as suggestion when i add multiple emails in the text field .